# How do I install Composer on a shared hosting?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have these things:

- the file http://api.odtu.lu/composer.phar
- http://api.odtu.lu/phpinfo.php
- ftp access
- cPanel
- Cron jobs on FreeBSD
- PHP, Perl, CGI-BIN, Python, Curl.

How can I install Composer? (My aim is to install [Restler](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/tree/v3rc5-Stable))

Edit: I do not have SSH access.

Comment: I followed the instructions on Composers website. http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-nix. You will want to use a terminal to ssh into your host. I use BlueHost so in the CPANEL I had to tell it to allow remote ssh connections, then use PuTTY and connect to run the command lines.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific web host.

Comment: If you have shell access on your shared host (you will need it for composer to work) then you don't have to do anything except to save `composer.phar` somewhere and make it executable.

Comment: @Rottingham, I didn't say that I have SSH.

Comment: @DanielA.White, what? no, this is very common, most of the shared hosts do not have SSH.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, I don't have shell access.

Comment: @ilhan If you don't have shell access you won't be able to use composer on that host. Instead you have to do it locally in development then upload your files with the populated `vendor/` and `composer.lock` to the shared host (like Kevin says below)

Comment: @dan, I have tried to extract composer.phar with 7-Zip, it was unable to extract the files. Then I have tried to run composer.phar by clicking on it, it didn't run, the browser tried to download the file.

Comment: @ilhan You do realize that a `PHAR` file is to be executed by the PHP interpreter? It should not be extracted and certainly not opened by a browser. As others have stated if you don't have shell access (ssh) then your only bet is to use composer locally and then copy over the `vendor/` directory.

Comment: @user555, can't I do this with Cron jobs?

Comment: @ilhan Well you could, but then you would have to delete the cron job manually. Composer was designed to run from the shell. If I were you I'd stay away from trying to push a square peg into round hole. Just install composer locally and copy over the `vendor/` dir, it will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: @user555, I have just installed EasyPHP to the computer I use, then Git, and then Composer. There are missing DLLs. I have tried with XAMP but there I cannot start Apache, probably because I do not have admin rights.

Comment: @ilhan If you have trouble with your WAMP stack you better ask a new question describing your problems in detail.

Comment: It can be installed using a PHP script, see [this previous question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530766/downloading-composer-via-php-script

Comment: @ilhan Did you solve it?

Comment: @Umair I have used a web site where you enter a composer.json file and it installs all the dependencies and makes a zip file for you to download the result. But I don't remember what web site it was. Just google "online composer php".

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It depends on the host, but you probably simply can't (you can't on my shared host on Rackspace Cloud Sites - I asked them).

What you can do is set up an environment on your dev machine that roughly matches your shared host, and do all of your management through the command line locally. Then when everything is set (you've pulled in all the dependencies, updated, managed with git, etc.) you can "push" that to your shared host over (s)FTP.

Comment: I'm having trouble installing some DDL files to EasyPHP and, and running XAMPP's Apache server. I might trie to install a Linux on Qemu. So I can install them there. What do you suggest?

Comment: EasyPHP, XAMPP, and WampServer didn't work (because they want admin rights I think). UwAmp worked. In Windows 7 without admin rights.

Comment: I've had issues all the various **MP servers on Windows. My brother likes XAMPP for that it's worth. I'm on OSX most of the times these days, and just started using Ampps. It's been pretty great so far, though I literally just installed it 2 days ago. :-)

Comment: with this method if in future i require a new dependency will i be able to install that directly of will i have to follow this same setup again?

Comment: Yes. You'll always have to set up everything locally and push it live over FTP (and possibly clean things out manually, if packages are removed, etc.).

Answer (score 53):

[This tutorial](http://purewebmedia.biz/article/2014/11/02/how-setup-drush-7-shared-hosting) worked for me, resolving my issues with /usr/local/bin permission issues and php-cli (which composer requires, and may aliased differently on shared hosting).

First run these commands to download and install composer:

```
cd ~
mkdir bin
mkdir bin/composer
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mv composer.phar bin/composer
```

Determine the location of your php-cli (needed later on):

```
which php-cli
```

(If the above fails, use `which php`)

It should return the path, such as /usr/bin/php-cli, /usr/php/54/usr/bin/php-cli, etc.

edit ~/.bashrc and make sure this line is at the top, adding it if it is not:

```
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

and then add this alias to the bottom (using the php-cli path that you determined earlier):

```
alias composer="/usr/bin/php-cli ~/bin/composer/composer.phar"
```

Finish with these commands:

```
source ~/.bashrc
composer --version
```

Comment: Some shared hosting you might need these commands instead:
DOWNLOAD: `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php55 -d suhosin.executor.include.whitelist=phar`

ALIAS: `alias composer="php55 -d suhosin.executor.include.whitelist=phar ~/bin/composer.phar"`

Comment: If you don't have access to cUrl, you can download composer via wget. `wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar`

Comment: I did not find the `[ - z ...` line to be necessary. Just needed to add the alias at the bottom.

Comment: I had to rerun "source ~/.bashrc" the next time I used SSH.

Comment: `~/.bashrc` didn't work for me but `~/.profile` did. (IONOS Shared Hosting)

Comment: If `which` doesn't work for you, you can use `whereis`. I wasn't able to let it work with `php`, and `php-cli` was not found. However, when I used `whereis php-cli`, and I used that path, it worked

Answer (score 28):

I have successfully installed Composer (and Laravel) on my shared hosting with only FTP access:

1. Download and install [PHPShell](http://phpshell.sourceforge.net/) on a shared hosting
2. In PHPShell's `config.php` add a user and an alias:

   `php = "php -d suhosin.executor.include.whitelist=phar"`
3. Log in to PHPShell and type: `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
4. When successfully installed, run Composer: `php composer.phar`

Comment: My shared hoster has proc_open disabled, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Same here @ConquerorsHaki

Comment: Try popen(), exec(), shell_exec(), passthru() or system().

Comment: But how do you run the the commands if you have only ftp access like i do with 000webhost

Comment: @IchHabsDrauf That's why you install PHPShell on your hosting using FTP and then run commands in it.

Comment: Does this solution still work even today? I tried it but fail to get Composer installed. Even though `step 3` doesn't give an error, `step 4` gives an error that it can't find `composer.phar`

Comment: @niutech you are awesome! this made my day

Answer (score 16):

You can do it that way:

- Create a directory where you want to install composer (let's say /home/your_username/composer)
- Go to this directory - `cd /home/your_username/composer`
- Then run the following command:

  `php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php`
- After that if you want to run composer, you can do it this way (in this caseyou must be in the composer's dir): `php composer.phar`
- As a next step, you can do this:

  `alias composer="/home/your_username/composer/composer.phar"`.

  And run commands like you do it normally: `$ composer install`

Hope that helps

Comment: some servers have a default bash file where you can put the alias

Comment: I already know that, but don't know how it happens, couse I am not very good with bash. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: probably you will find a file call .bashrc outside the public folder and you can put the alias there. You need to restart the ssh console (close and open)

Answer (score 5):

I was able to install composer on HostGator's shared hosting. Logged in to SSH with Putty, right after login you should be in your home directory, which is usually /home/username, where username is your username obviously. Then ran the curl command posted by @niutech above. This downloaded the composer to my home directory and it's now accessible and working well.

Answer (score 5):

SIMPLE SOLUTION (tested on Red Hat):

run command: `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`

to use it: `php composer.phar`

SYSTEM WIDE SOLLUTION (tested on Red Hat):

run command: `mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

to use it: `composer update`

now you can call composer from any directory.

Source: http://www.agix.com.au/install-composer-on-centosredhat/

Comment: NB: if you move composer.phar to /usr/local/bin/composer, you rename `composer.phar` in `composer`. Then the command you have to run is `composer` and not `composer.phar`. I edited your post with the correction.
However, this solution will probably not work in a shared hosting, as the user will not likely be able to move a file to a system folder.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the time you can't - depending on the host. You can contact the support team where your hosting is subscribed to, and if they confirmed that it is really not allowed, you can just set up the composer on your dev machine, and commit and push all dependencies to your live server using Git or whatever you prefer.