# How to install composer on a shared hosting?

Tags: composer-php, shared-hosting

I'm trying to install composer on a shared hosting , GoGeek from siteground , what's the best way to do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Composer on a shared hosting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894518/how-do-i-install-composer-on-a-shared-hosting)

Comment: I installed composer on GoGeek from SiteGround. Please see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49745082/2993088.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to install Composer on the live server. Run it locally on the machine that uploads the other code to your shared hosting server.

Why? Because it works, and you will see any errors during `composer install` before such a failure takes your site offline. Note that any of the used services (packagist.org, GitHub, Bitbucket and so on) never have 100% uptime, and it will be annoying if the one you need is down when you need it during an update.

Answer (score 1):

On SiteGround (as per your current account), it's already installed. [Here](https://www.siteground.co.uk/kb/install-laravel/) it states "Composer is pre-installed on all of our servers."