# What is the best way to install package in laravel 5 on server?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have done a laravel package (as plugin), now i wanted to know that what is convenient way to install in laravel on server. I have searched about that, there is some tutorials but most of them are installing with github. I don't want to add my code on github.

So is this possible to install my package on laravel without uploading code on github? Can anyone guide me the way to install my package on laravel.

I would like to appreciate. Thank You

Comment: The convenient way is that first upload your code on git then pull on server.Remember git,doesn't mean only github you can use bitbucket also.Rather you can use svn or just zip your folder and upload you code on server.

Comment: @ImtiazPabel thank you so much for guideline, can you kindly share here some tutorial if you know.

Comment: tutorial for what?git or svn?

Comment: @ImtiazPabel any of them, which one is more secure?

Comment: you can follow this to learn git http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

Comment: @ImtiazPabel actually i'm finding way to install package in laravel on server, i have already experience github. git is almost same as github

Comment: Github uses git, as does bitbucket, gitlab, etc... Are you saying you don't want to use git at all or you don't want to use github because it is public (unless you pay)? If you don't want to use git at all then you will need to use FTP or SFTP to get the files to the server. If you just don't want a public repo use bitbucket they have free private repos.

Comment: @Pitchinnate Yes exactly that's what i want. But problem is that laravel installing the packages through composer (I have to update the composer for the integration), so once i upload the files then what will be procedure of composer update on server.

Comment: Composer creates a file called `composer.lock`. This file is used to keep track of the versions of packages you have installed. When your code is pulled to a new server you just need to call `composer install` and it will install all of your dependencies.

Comment: @RossWilson Sure, but how can i access composer in cmd from server?

Comment: Are you on a windows server?

Comment: @RossWilson its on bluehost (I think linux server)

Comment: Ok. I only asked because `cmd` is usually used for windows machines, `cli` is the usually abbreviation for linux. You would access composer in the same way you currently are. If it's not installed you can use this to get you started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894518/how-do-i-install-composer-on-a-shared-hosting

Comment: @RossWilson Thank you, the above comment has useful detail.