# Error running 'composer install' on cpanel server using PuTTY

Tags: php, json, symfony, composer-php

I have connected my cPanel access using PuTTY to install Composer to be able to run my Symfony application. On running `composer install` command on the server, I am getting this message as a throwback

> composer could not find a `composer.json` file in `/home/mydomain`
>       to initialize a project please create a `composer.json` file

I am kind of confused as I don't know where to create the `composer.json` on my server.

Please can someone assist am a newbie to this.

Comment: Did you already install Composer on your server or did you try to install Composer by running `composer install`. If it was 2nd then please read the Composer manual how to install Composer first. You might also find some good tutorials on google how to install and use Composer.

Comment: I have browsed into the root of my project I uploaded I am doing composer self-update. I am getting permission denied

Comment: make sure the user which is running `composer self-update` has the rights to change files in the directory where you installed Composer.

Comment: how do I edit the privilege. I logged in as admin

Comment: This depends on your OS. And I'm sorry that I have to say this, but these are basics an admin should know! If you don't know how to check permissions of a directory you should not be admin (at least if we are talking about a production environment). If this is for educational purpose only, I suggest to read some tutorials to learn the basics of your OS first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move to your project's root directory (Where the structure is App/, src/, Web/, composer.json).

Execute composer install from there.

If you're project is empty ATM just create a composer.json file where you want your project to be and put in it the content of the composer.json of your working local project

Comment: could not open input file composer.phar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894518/how-do-i-install-composer-on-a-shared-hosting

Comment: update your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Comment: Warning: require_once(/home/domain/public_html/../app/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/domain/public_html/app.php on line 6

Comment: If I try to access my sight

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344296/unable-to-run-composer-phar-update-on-the-server