# Unable to run 'composer.phar update' on the server

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am trying to run Symfony application in the production server. I have uploaded my web files to `public_html`  folder. I have installed Composer in my project resource using `composer.phar install`. Now I am trying to update Composer on the server I am getting this message/error

> php composer.phar update
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> ```
> Problem 1
>     - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v2.5.12
>     - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.12
>     - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.11
>     - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.10
>     - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.9
>     - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.8
>     - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.7
>     - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.6
>     - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.5
>     - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.4
>     - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.3
>     - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.2
>     - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.1
>     - friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 2.1.0 requires symfony/finder ^2.7|^3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/finder[v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9, v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.10, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4].
>     - friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 2.1.1 requires symfony/debug ^2.7|^3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/debug[v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9, v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.10, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.10 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.11 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.12 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.13 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.14 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.15 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.16 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.17 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.18 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.19 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.2 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.20 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.21 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.22 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.23 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.24 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.3 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.4 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.5 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.6 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.7 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.8 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.9 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.8.0 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.8.1 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.8.10 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.8.11 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.8.12 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.8.13 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.8.14 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.8.15 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.8.16 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.8.17 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.8.2 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.8.3 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.8.4 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.8.5 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.8.6 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.8.7 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.8.8 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.8.9 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.0.0 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.0.1 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.0.2 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.0.3 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.0.4 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.0.5 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.0.6 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.0.7 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.0.8 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.0.9 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.1.0 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.1.1 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.1.10 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.1.2 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.1.3 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.1.4 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.1.5 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.1.6 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.1.7 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.1.8 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.1.9 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.2.0 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.2.1 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.2.2 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.2.3 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v3.2.4 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.11|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.12|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.13|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.14|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.15|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.16|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.17|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.18|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.19|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.20|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.21|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.22|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.23|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.24|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.7.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.8.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.8.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.8.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.8.11|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.8.12|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.8.13|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.8.14|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.8.15|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.8.16|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.8.17|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.8.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.8.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.8.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.8.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.8.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.8.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.8.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v2.8.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.0.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.0.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.0.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.0.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.0.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.0.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.0.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.0.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.0.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.0 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - symfony/debug v2.7.1 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.1.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.1.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.1.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.1.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.1.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.1.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.1.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.1.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.1.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.1.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.2.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.2.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.2.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - don't install symfony/finder v3.2.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
>     - Installation request for symfony/symfony 2.5.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9].
>     - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle ^2.1 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle[2.1.0, 2.1.1].
> ```

please what could be wrong and how can this issue be tackled as this is weird to me. Kindly assist

Comment: please show your composer.json

Comment: Here you say you want to "update Composer on the server", but in a comment on Peh's answer you say you want to "update the dependencies in composer" (which doesn't really make any sense). And here you say you've already run `composer install`. Normally that is all that is required. _What are you actually trying to accomplish?_

Answer (score 1):

> I have installed Composer in my project resource using `composer.phar install`.

First of all `composer.phar install` doesn't install Composer! It installs your dependencies. See [Installing Dependencies](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies)

Second: Never run `composer update` in a production environment (on server). Always use `composer install` to install dependencies in a production environment. See [Never run 'composer update' in production why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42065931/never-run-composer-update-in-production-why)

Comment: Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/domain/public_html/../app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/domain/public_html/app.php on line 6

Comment: after installing composer

Comment: this is the reason I am thinking of updating composer

Comment: The only thing I personally can honestly recommend to you is reading the manuals and tutorials to learn more about how Composer has to be used. You can't learn it by posting cryptic error messages and asking why isn't this working. Take your time, Composer isn't a tool that you learn in 2 minutes.

Comment: Ok. I am trying to update composer offline and I am getting the same error message as posted above..................If composer should not be updated on the prod. server then

Comment: `composer update` does **not** update Composer it updates the dependencies in your project. Please read [ask] to learn how to ask a precisely and correct question. Mostly nobody can help you if you are just posting error messages.