# Laravel 5.0 getting error while reading excel file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am in working Laravel 5.0. My task is about read Excel/CSV files and all that.
But can't able to continue due to following error Fatal error.

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_Shared_Font' not found in
>   /home/content/28/10055228/html/distribution/config/excel.php on line
>   182

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
        "phpoffice/phpexcel": "1.8.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
```

**/config/app.php (providers and aliases array)**

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\BusServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\EventServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider',
    'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider',

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Aliases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
| is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
| the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
|
*/

'aliases' => [

    'App'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
    'Artisan'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan',
    'Auth'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth',
    'Blade'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade',
    'Bus'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus',
    'Cache'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache',
    'Config'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config',
    'Cookie'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie',
    'Crypt'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt',
    'DB'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB',
    'Eloquent'  => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',
    'Event'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event',
    'File'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\File',
    'Hash'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash',
    'Input'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input',
    'Inspiring' => 'Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring',
    'Lang'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang',
    'Log'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log',
    'Mail'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail',
    'Password'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password',
    'Queue'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue',
    'Redirect'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect',
    'Redis'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis',
    'Request'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request',
    'Response'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response',
    'Route'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route',
    'Schema'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema',
    'Session'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session',
    'Storage'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage',
    'URL'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL',
    'Validator' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator',
    'View'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\View',
    'Excel'     => 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel',

],
```

Please correct me.

Thanks

Comment: after adding `"maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
        "phpoffice/phpexcel": "1.8.1"` did you run `composer install` ? which caused issue first or second ?

Comment: actually the server is shared so i am not able to do that. and i have implement this on localhost first ( working fine ). on server it is getting error.

Comment: You are not loaded all related file in vendor folder, until you run `composer install`

Comment: Run composer update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user2486 already pointed out, you have to run `composer install` on your server. Even on shared hosting it is possible to install composer, but this depends on the hoster. You can ask them or have a look at [How do I install Composer on a shared hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894518/how-do-i-install-composer-on-a-shared-hosting)

If it is not possible, you should get another hosting package where it is possible. Otherwise push the whole application (including `vendor` folder) to your server. **Hint:** This is not recommended, but more a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below command

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel
OR
composer require "maatwebsite/excel":"~2.1.0"
```