# Class 'Anand\LaravelPaytmWallet\PaytmWalletServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I tried to install Laravel Paytm Wallet plugin from AnandSiddharth using composer on my GoDaddy deluxe shared hosting server. I was unable to install it in laravel folder. I copied the vendor files from my desktop to the server and updated config/app.php page in providers and alias category. Then the web server throws an error

```
Class 'Anand\LaravelPaytmWallet\PaytmWalletServiceProvider' not found
```

I tried to install it in server home folder and move to vendor but it is showing the same error. The composer.json file gets updated. You can see the screenshots. Any working solution will be helpful. Thanks.

error Log

```
FatalThrowableError in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'Anand\LaravelPaytmWallet\PaytmWalletServiceProvider' not found in ProviderRepository.php line 146
at ProviderRepository->createProvider('Anand\LaravelPaytmWallet\PaytmWalletServiceProvider') in ProviderRepository.php line 114
at ProviderRepository->compileManifest(array('Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider', 'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider', 'App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider', 'App\Providers\EventServiceProvider', 'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider', 'Anand\LaravelPaytmWallet\PaytmWalletServiceProvider')) in ProviderRepository.php line 60
at ProviderRepository->load(array('Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider', 'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider', 'App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider', 'App\Providers\EventServiceProvider', 'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider', 'Anand\LaravelPaytmWallet\PaytmWalletServiceProvider')) in Application.php line 507
at Application->registerConfiguredProviders() in RegisterProviders.php line 17
at RegisterProviders->bootstrap(object(Application)) in Application.php line 203
at Application->bootstrapWith(array('Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\DetectEnvironment', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders')) in Kernel.php line 222
at Kernel->bootstrap() in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

config/app.php

```
Anand\LaravelPaytmWallet\PaytmWalletServiceProvider::class,
```

Comment: 1 > on your remote server check `vendor/composer/autload_psr4.php` and check if this exists in the array ->  Anand\\LaravelPaytmWallet.




2> verify in vendor folder if this directory exists  `anandsiddharth/laravel-paytm-wallet/src`
if either of them doesnt exists prefer installing the package locally and then upload back to server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894518/how-do-i-install-composer-on-a-shared-hosting

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 5.0 use version ^1.0.0
For Laravel 6.0 use version ^1.0.0
For Laravel 7.0 use version ^1.0.0
For Laravel 8.0 use version ^2.0.0

check version and install
composer require anandsiddharth/laravel-paytm-wallet:1.0.0

composer require vendor/package:version

Comment: Please share more details. What makes you think that this resolves the problem? Keep in mind that a good explanation helps others to learn from your answer