# How to use a package in PHP without installation?

Tags: php

I have a hosting service on a server, so I do not have access to server commands and cannot install [Web3.php](https://github.com/web3p/web3.php).

I can only use it in the PHP 7.4 program:

```
use Web3\Web3;
use Web3\Providers\HttpProvider;
use Web3\RequestManagers\HttpRequestManager;

$web3 = new Web3('https://...');
```

But it produces error in the last line:

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'Web3\Web3' not found in /home/...
```

When I import the web3.php:

```
include "./Web3/Web3.php";
```

it says:

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'Web3\RequestManagers\HttpRequestManager' not found in /home/...
```

How can I run this code properly by importing another files? and witch files?

Is there any other way to run the code?

Regards.

Comment: How did you get the `Web3.php` library files on the server? Manually download them and upload them? If so, it seems like you'd need to do what `composer` would do for you – `require_once` all the files in the `src` folder of their repository. You'd probably need to download [the projects listed in the `dependencies` of the `composer.json`](https://github.com/web3p/web3.php/blob/master/composer.json) and `require_once` all of their files too and if *those* have any dependencies again, you'd probably have to do the same for those too, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Composer on a shared hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894518/how-do-i-install-composer-on-a-shared-hosting)

Comment: You have to create an autoloader that autoloads classes from Web3/ folder and include that instead.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you may use a similar hosting environment (same OS, same PHP version, etc.) which supports composer, and then use the following command to install web3

```
composer require web3p/web3.php dev-master
```

Then , test and verify that everything is fine, and then use FTP to push (i.e. download and then upload) the whole folder to the shared hosting.

However, please note that web3 requires listening on port 8545, so in case your shared hosting blocks this port then you need to talk with them and fix this issue, otherwise it may not work unless you can switch to another port

Comment: I don't have access to server SSH.  I can only use CPanel.

Comment: If you have CPanel, you can use FTP (Note my suggestion: you need to find ANOTHER similar server to install web3 thru composer (even XAMPP may do), then use FTP to upload the whole directory to your shared hosting)