# Installing composer.phar

Tags: php, composer-php

I've been trying to install `composer.phar` to my `HostGator` website. However, I come across this error:

```
[~/public_html/flarum]# php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- flarum/core v0.1.0-beta.4 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.45) or value of "config.platform.php" in composer.json does not satisfy that requirement.
- flarum/core v0.1.0-beta.3 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.45) or value of "config.platform.php" in composer.json does not satisfy that requirement.
- flarum/flarum-ext-suspend v0.1.0-beta.3 requires flarum/core ^0.1.0-beta.3 -> satisfiable by flarum/core[v0.1.0-beta.3, v0.1.0-beta.4].
- Installation request for flarum/flarum-ext-suspend ^0.1.0 -> satisfiable by flarum/flarum-ext-suspend[v0.1.0-beta.3].
```

I have updated my `PHP` to the newest via the `cPanel`.

If there is any help at all that I could get on this it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what's the output of `/usr/bin/env php -v`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use PHP Composer on HostGator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887666/how-to-use-php-composer-on-hostgator)

Comment: Is there a `"platform"` config in `composer.json`

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP version is too low for Flarum. You need 55 or better 56.

Enable and use a higher PHP version on HostGator.

To find the other PHP versions take a look at the `/opt/` folder.

`# /opt/php56/bin/php composer.phar install`

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this link
http://laravel.io/forum/02-13-2014-how-to-install-laravel-on-a-hostgator-shared-server

and install flarum with following
~/composer create-project flarum/flarum ~/public_html/flarum --stability=beta

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”

Comment: The article linked here solved my issue perfectly. Once I made the bashrc edits and changed the php source to use the updated version (5.6) it then worked perfectly to make hostgator use an update php by default for composer. Thanks a ton!