# How to setup composer on hostgator shared hosting?

Tags: php, firebase, composer-php, web-hosting, website-deployment

I have a custom PHP website that uses PHP firebase admin SDK along with composer (Dependency manager). The website is working perfectly on my localhost.

when I try to upload my website to the public_html Directory of Hostgator hosting then I can't see the website.

I think it is due to the composer as Hostgator shared hosting don't support composer by default.

I just want to know possible solutions that can be used to make my project live on my server.

please help me

Comment: If you copied **everything required** up to the server using FTP from your localhost, it should work, composer does not have to be used, even though it would make things easier

Comment: Hostgator does have shell access. You may need to contact Billing or Support to enable it. Once it's enabled, you can log in and use composer to update/install the vendor directory

Comment: Possible Dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887666/how-to-use-php-composer-on-hostgator

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I copied all files using ftp but still, it is not working. I don't know whether it is the composer's issue or something else.

Comment: Or another Possible Dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894518/how-do-i-install-composer-on-a-shared-hosting

Comment: Did you check the Error logs?

Comment: i have access to shell

Comment: no, let me check it

Comment: There are no errors in the error logs